# Merging two iOS frameworks to one

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, frameworks, libtool

I have a framework I'm developing - `Mine.framwork` - and a third party framework that I use and that I instruct my clients to link to their app - `ThirdParty.framework`.

I want to make my clients' life a bit easier and just merge these two into one framework `New.framework`.

I tried using `libtool` as follows:

```
libtool -static -o New.framework/Versions/A/New Mine.framework/Versions/A/Mine ThirdParty.framework/Versions/A/ThirdParty
```

When I tried using `New.framework` I didn't get any exception, but nothing happened. Is it even possible if I don't have the source code for the second framework? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually a bad idea. What if your client wants to use a different version of `ThirdParty.framework`? Or imagine you would include the symbols of `ThirdParty.framework` but another framework would do the same: you'd end up with duplicate symbol conflicts that cannot be resolved.

Comment: @DarkDust I'm not sure but it looks like cocoapods do exactly this.

Comment: @Mateusz: Not exactly. Depending on the configuration, CocoaPods does produce a static library but only as an intermediate product. The static library produced by CocoaPods is _not_ meant to be distributed, whereas OPs framework is.